# Difference between scipy.stats.multivariate_normal and numpy.random.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am not sure if this is a statistics question or a coding question, but I am having a bit of a hard time understanding the difference between scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov) and numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov).

Can someone check my understanding and correct me if I am completely off-track? The multivariate_normal.pdf() function in scipy requires an input of the data x, while numpy's does not. I am thinking that the one in scipy is trying to fit x into a Gaussian distribution, while the one in numpy creates a gaussian component from scratch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs, you see that:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html
  `pdf` is `Probability density function.` So it would just compute the multivariate `pdf` (i.e. the mathematical N-dimemsion Gaussian function) at given `x`.
- https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html `Draw random samples from a multivariate normal distribution` Not sure how to better explain this...